# Location returned from Android Geocoder and GMSGeocoder in GoogleMaps SDK for iOS are different

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, android-maps-v2, reverse-geocoding

I am using an android's geocoder([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int))) for reverse geocoding whilst using Google's SDK for iOS using reverseGeocodeCoordinate method ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder)) but the location name returned for the two different classed in Android an iOS is different. It would be helpful if your experiences helped my confusion. Thanks

Eg: PWC Australia returned 35 Hickson road Bangaroo using reverseGeocodeCoordinate from GMSGeocoder class.